# Check if external app opened. UI testing xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

In my app I am opening spotify using:

```
let kSpotifyAppLink = "spotify:app:mymusicapp"
var url = NSURL(string: kSpotifyAppLink)

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) {
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

Is it possible to check in UI tests if the spotify actually opened after button click?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Xcode UI tests, or are you unit testing your UI? The code above is not using UI testing code.

Comment: It's not my testing code. It's code I am using to open external App. The question is: is it possible to check in UI tests if it actually opened.

Comment: If `UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!)` returns `true` and you're opening it with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)` you can be assured that it has opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to detect whether other apps are open since XCTest only has a connection to your app, not Spotify's. For security reasons, iOS doesn't allow your app to know which app is in the foreground, only that your app needs to transition away from being in the foreground.